# how to implement Coroutine async/await on BaseViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm using Retrofit with Coroutine using this structure to hit the API requests in my app but at some screens I send multiple request and I want to only show data if the all requests was loaded but I can't do that using this structure?

```
  interface MyApi{
        @GET(API_DATA)
        suspend fun getDataA(): Response<BaseResponse<MyApiResponse>>
    
        @GET(API_DATA)
        suspend fun getDataB(): Response<BaseResponse<MyApiResponse>>

       @GET(API_DATA)
        suspend fun getDataC(): Response<BaseResponse<MyApiResponse>>
    }
```

//

```
 class MyApiCalls(private val myApi: MyApi) {
     suspend fun getDataA() =
            myApi.getDataA()
    
     suspend fun getDataB() =
            myApi.getDataB()

     suspend fun getDataC() =
            myApi.getDataC()
    }
```

//

```
class MyRepository(
    private val myApiCalls: MyApiCalls
    ) : BaseRepository()  {
        suspend fun getDataA() = myApiCalls.getDataA()
        suspend fun getDataB() = myApiCalls.getDataB()
        suspend fun getDataC() = myApiCalls.getDataC()
}
```

//

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val repository: MyRepository,
) : BaseViewModel(repository) {
    val dataAStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()
    val dataBStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()
    val dataCStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()
    fun getDataA() {
        performNetworkCall({
            repository.getDataA()
        }, dataAStatus )

    }

    fun getDataB() {
        performNetworkCall({
            repository.getDataB()
        }, dataBStatus)

    }

  fun getDataC() {
        performNetworkCall({
            repository.getDataC()
        }, dataCStatus)

    }

}
```

//

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(private val repository: BaseRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val showNetworkError = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
    val statusToken = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()
    val logoutStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()
    val refreshTokenStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Status>()

    fun <D> performNetworkCall(
        apiCall: suspend () -> Response<D>,
        status: SingleLiveEvent<Status>,
        doOnSuccess: (responseData: D?) -> Unit = {},
        doOnFailure: (() -> Any) = {}
    ) {
        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    try {
                        status.postValue(Status.Loading)
                        val response = apiCall.invoke()
                        when {
                     
                            response.code() in 200..300 -> {
                                doOnSuccess(response.body())
                                status.postValue(Status.Success(response.body()))
                            }
                     
                            else -> {
                                doOnFailure()
                                status.postValue(Status.Error(
                    errorCode = ERRORS.DEFAULT_ERROR,
                    message = repository.getString(R.string.default_error)
                )
            )
                
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        doOnFailure()
                       status.postValue(
                Status.Error(
                    errorCode = ERRORS.DEFAULT_ERROR,
                    message = repository.getString(R.string.default_error)
                )
            )
                    }
                }
            }
        } else
            status.postValue(
                Status.Error(
                    errorCode = ERRORS.NO_INTRERNET,
                    message = repository.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection)
                )
            )
    }
}
```

I want to use aysnc await to read data from getDataA and getDataB on my activity/Fragment how to implement that using this structure and also keep the ability to use single request in other api requests

Comment: "how to implement that using this structure" - it seems you can't, you need to create another structure, for example call it `performMultipleNetworkCalls` and implement it the way you need. Do you want to call `getDataA()`, `getDataB()` and `getDataC()` in parallel and then somehow combine their results?

Comment: @Sergey yes that's exactly what I want to implement

Answer (score 2):

To call functions in parallel you can use `async` builder:

```
fun performRequests() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val request1 = async { repository.getDataA() }
        val request2 = async { repository.getDataB() }
        val request3 = async { repository.getDataC() }
         // all three requests run in parallel
        
        val response1 = request1.await()
        val response2 = request2.await()
        val response3 = request3.await()

        //... use those responses to get data, notify UI
    }
}
```

---

In your current structure, I don't think there is a need in calling `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in `performNetworkCall()` method, unless you want the callbacks `doOnSuccess` and `doOnFailure` to be called in background thread.

---

**UPDATE**

Try to use next calls to reuse your current structure:

```
performNetworkCall({performRequests()}, status)

suspend fun performRequests(): Response<...> = coroutineScope {
    val request1 = async { repository.getDataA() }
    val request2 = async { repository.getDataB() }
    val request3 = async { repository.getDataC() }
    // all three requests run in parallel

    val response1 = request1.await()
    val response2 = request2.await()
    val response3 = request3.await()

    //... use those responses to compose a general Response object
    val generalResponse: Response<...> = "..."

    generalResponse
}
```

I used `coroutineScope` function, it is designed for parallel decomposition of work. When any child coroutine in this scope fails, this scope fails and all the rest of the children are cancelled.

Comment: I will do it like that    
 viewModelScope.launch {
            async { getDataA() }.await()
            async { getDataB() }.await()
            async { getDataC() }.await()

        }

Comment: which means I will use the method of viewModel inside one method loads all the requests on async await , Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: If you want the functions to be called in parallel, it is not a good solution. In your example each function will wait untill previous one is finished. It is similar if you just write `viewModelScope.launch { val a = getDataA() val b = getDataB() ... }

Comment: by `getData..()` I mean the `suspend` functions from `MyRepository`, i.e.: `viewModelScope.launch { val a = repository.getDataA() val b = repository.getDataB() ... }`

Comment: I need to pass response1 , response2 , response3 back to my method performNetworkCall which take Status object  but the response1 was in BaseResponse object how can I achieve that?

Comment: I thought about your current structure once again, and it seems there is some workaround for this, but in this case you need to compose `Response` object out of the three objects. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The response of the three requests is different and I need to pass it to different status object inside my ViewModel?

Comment: I don't know, it's up to you, you can use just one status object if it suits your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dataAStatus` and `dataBStatus`. You can have one single live data like `SingleLiveEvent<Pair<Status,Status>>()`.

```
 val dataStatus = SingleLiveEvent<Pair<Status,Status>()
    private fun getAllData(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val dataFromA = myApiCalls.getDataA()
            val dataFromB = myApiCalls.getDataB()
            dataStatus.postValue(Pair(dataFromA,dataFromB))
            
        }
    }
```

Here `myApiCalls.getDataA()` and `myApiCalls.getDataB()` should be returning `status`.

And then observe on this live data (`dataStatus`) in your activity or fragment.

```
private fun observeData() {
        viewModel.dataStatus.observe(this){
            val firstData = it.first
            val secondData = it.second
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if I have a third api to hit that will not gonna work anymore, also how to use this on performNetworkCall method which I already have in my baseviewmodel structure?